# Filter property values by type in wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to set up a SPARQL query that lists museums for a specified country. My main goal is to find the city the museum is located.

I'm new to wikidata, just started.
So far, I have used the property `?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity` to find the city. The problem is that for many countries, this gives me not only the city, but also the state, e.g. in Switzerland it gives me Zurich and in another Canton of Zurich. 
Is it possible to restrict the search such that it only gives me the city?

```
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?museum ?museumLabel ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entityLabel 
        WHERE {
  ?museum wdt:P17 wd:Q39;   # countries          
          wdt:P31 ?type.
          ?type (wdt:P279*) wd:Q33506.

         # If available, get the "en" entry, use native language as fallback:
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,de". }

  # get location if available
  OPTIONAL { ?museum wdt:P131 ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity. } 

}
order by ?museum
```

I would like to get a single row per museum that includes the city the museum is located in. I don't want several rows with the same museum that display different geographical hierarchies (state / city).

Comment: if you just want to have cities, you have to state this in the query: `OPTIONAL { ?museum wdt:P131 ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity. ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 } `

Comment: and do `SELECT DISTINCT ` to avoid duplicate rows.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: A follow up question: I noticed that your solution might not capture 'towns' and 'villages' that are too small to be considered 'cities'. Is there a way to get those, too?

Comment: `OPTIONAL { VALUES ?locationType {wd:Q532 wd:Q515 wd:Q3957} ?museum wdt:P131 ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity. ?located_in_the_administrative_territorial_entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?locationType. } `

Comment: Thanks. I start to understand how that works.